# Efficient way for finding formulas in a string

Tags: python, regex

say i have the string `testString = "x=4+y and y = 8"`

I want to run `findIndices(testString)` and get back a list of indices containing formula items

i.e. this should return `[0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14]`

I'm thinking this would work

```
find equalSigns
foreach equalSign
   look to the left until you see a space not preceded by an operator
        put current index in  formulalist
   look to the right until you see a space not preceded by an operator
        put current index in formulalist
   put the equalSign index in the formulalist

return formulalist
```

1) is there a more efficient way in python? What is it? (regexes?)

2) if this is efficient: how do I write the "look to the left" and "look to the right" subroutines?

Comment: Why are 11 and 13 in the list? Those are white spaces.

Comment: It's easy enough to hack something up that works for one case. You really need to write down the grammar before you can think about parsing it.

Comment: **Try something and then show us.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're going for, but

```
string.split("=")  
string.index("=")
```

for instance:

```
In [1]: a= "y = 25*x  + 42*z"
In [2]: a.split("=")
Out[2]: ['y ', ' 25*x  + 42*z']
In [3]: a.index("=")
Out[3]: 2
```

might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2):

As noted gnibbler's comment, write down the grammar before you think about parsing it.   That said, if a “formula” were a string with no whitespace in it and at least one equal-sign in it, the following function would return a list of formulas from a string:

```
def formulas(s):
   return filter(lambda x: '=' in x, s.split())
```

For example:
`formulas('x=4+y and y=8')` produces `['x=4+y', 'y=8']`
`formulas("x=4+y and y = 8")` produces `['x=4+y', '=']`
`formulas('x=4+y and y=8 etc z=47+38*x + y')` produces `['x=4+y', 'y=8', 'z=47+38*x']`

Of course these results are not lists of indices, and the string `y = 8` was not treated as a formula.  However, in the bigger picture it may be more useful to you to simplify the grammar and to split your original string into separate formulas before doing more-detailed processing.